# Joomla Article Answers with attachments

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I have a page with a list of articles of a given category, what I'm trying to do is to give the possibility to "answer" an article ("comment" if you prefer) but this answer needs to be a text + attached doc.

My question is : 
What Plugin/component/solution comes to your mind?

I'm trying to figure out if there's any existing plugin that can handle this.

Right now, I'm looking into the comments extension list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few Q&A options for Joomla that I know of:

[jAnswers](http://www.thefactory.ro/articles/articles/janswers-revealed---yahoo-answers-clone-script.html) - is a **commercial** plugin that clones Yahoo answers.

[IknAnswers](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum/9388) - another Yahoo clone and again its **commercial**.

Its a bit disappointing there don't seem to be any free Q&A solutions out there for Joomla that I've found.

If you are willing to just accept comments then [JComments](http://www.joomlatune.com/jcomments.html) is one of the most popular. I don't think you can attach documents with JComments though.